# Edit MP4 Hex data to vertically or horizontally flip video in a lossless manner

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, lossless, flip

I am trying to do something similar to the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031557/rotate-mp4-videos-without-re-encoding) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1307158/change-rotation-flag-in-mp4-video-without-losing-metadata/), but with a small difference. I am trying to flip the video along the Y or X axes instead of doing a rotation.

The solution in those threads to modify the rotation matrix seems like the perfect approach, and I am able to modify the parameters to perform the rotation. But I cannot figure out what the values should be for flipping the video.

To quote from those threads:

> - no rotation:
>
> ```
> 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
> 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
> 40
> ```
>
> - 180°:
>
> ```
> FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 40
> ```
>
> - 90° cw:
>
> ```
> 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 40
> ```
>
> - 90° ccw:
>
> ```
> 00 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 40
> ```

I was unable to find documentation online that talks about what the values in those two lines indicate, hence I was not able to achieve the flip.

I tried alternatives with ffmpeg as well, but I run into issues:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf hflip output.mp4
```

... This re-encodes the file because of the "vf" flag that applies filtering.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=0,transpose=1" output.mp4
```

... This too re-encodes the file because of the "vf" flag.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -metadata:s:v rotate="90" -codec copy output.mp4
```

... This works without re-encoding (and is almost as fast as directly editing the file), but obviously rotation does not achieve a flip. Is there a way I could use the `metadata` option with `transpose`?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=0,transpose=1" -codec copy output.mp4
```

... This gives me an error saying that filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? How would I achieve a video flip without encoding? Even if I end up encoding, how can I do it in a lossless manner?

I would have posted on the threads I have referenced above for help, but I am a new user here and cannot post comments on threads as a result.

Comment: In terms of the matrix mathematics, for horz. flip, you have to change, in `no rotation`, the first `00 01` to `FF FF`. For vert. flip, change the 2nd `00 01` to `FF FF`. However, it seems most players only check if the matrix values correspond to a pure rotation transform. If not, the image is untouched.

Comment: @Gyan - So the interpretation of this is really player-specific? In other words the only true way to do this is to re-encode?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: it's not really the interpretation that changes but whether the player checks for pure flips. Generally, they don't.